# How can I find out what scope a user has based off their access token in the Instagram api?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I can't find the answer to this in the developer Instagram documentation, nor through Google, so I was hoping someone on here could answer me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just tell the scopes by looking at `access_token`.

One way you can do is write a simple script to make API calls using this `access_token`

- Make a GET API call to get a photo other than your - `public_content`
- Make a GET API call to get self followers - `following_list`
- Make a POST API to like, comment and follow - `like` `comment`
  `relationship`

(the last one if not really recommended if you dont really have permission to like/comment on someone behalf, it may show up on notification in app and they may revoke that access_token if they feel they did not like/comment on something)

Comment: But there is no way to have a text display of what scopes I have?

Comment: you can write a script that you enter `access_token` and it will display text of scopes, no direct way